# Browser window size statistics?

Tags: browsers, statistics, resolution

I was wondering, are there any statistics available on what size users have their browser set to nowadays? I know the screen resolutions (we have analytics, which shows those as well) but I doubt a lot of people with 1280*xxx and higher still browse full-screen though.

My boss is determined to keep our website 900px wide though, because that way people with 1800*xxx resolutions can have two browser windows next to eachother without having to scroll horizontally. I have never seen anyone browse with two adjacent browser windows like that except here at my current job, so I'm kind of doubting whether this is the best decision or just his personal preference.

Anyone that can help out here?

Comment: the answer you accepted is obviously outdated, you should reconsider changing your decision and pursue for newer stats. See also: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/719/what-do-when-wrong-answer-is-accepted-as-best-answer

Comment: @Litso, I've never seen anyone browse with two browsers side by side either I think that method of browsing the web is extremely rare. I would look at the 960 or 1140 grid system http://cssgrid.net/ and http://960.gs/ 960px has been very popular design wise for a few years. Now even wider resolutions are coming around. 900px is just a random number and to close to 899 lol

Answer (score 6):

### Google Browser Size

http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/

This is a super tool which should fill all your needs, allowing you to even load in a URL and see what it looks like in different resolutions.

[image]

Comment: Damn, that is awesome. How did that not pop up in Google when I searched for it?

Comment: @Litso, yeah it is great!  One thing to remember is if your page is centrally aligned with a fixed width, you should resize your browser window smaller so the margins on either side of the content reduce.

Comment: Superb tool, thank you for the link. Until now I have been using StatCounter's Global Reports (http://gs.statcounter.com/) for Resolution & browser stats as they have nice graphs there but this Google tool is brilliant. +1 vote

Comment: Is the information on the Google Browser Size tool up-to-date? The image it uses to overlay is called: http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/static/2009-11-18-day_google_com_100.png So I'm assuming it may be outdated.

Comment: The googlelabs site has not been updated since 2009.
Given that growth in use of both large monitors and small ipads, I'm not sure this data is going to be too helpful now.
Also I would guess the average monitor sizes will vary by country.

Comment: This site no longer exists.

Answer (score 5):

There are up-to-date stats at http://gs.statcounter.com/

Just select "Screen resolution" from the stat dropdown. At the time of this writing, it seems that 1366 * 768 is the rage.

Comment: Awesome, but it's still only about screen resolution, not browser viewport size.

Comment: The closest I can get to a concrete number is the one used by 960.gs: http://www.cameronmoll.com/archives/001220.html (between 40 and 50px in horizontal used by the chrome and scrollbars).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.impressivewebs.com/browser-usage-stats/

A collection of potential web statistic providers and information.

Comment: This statistics actually answers different question. It's not the screen resolution that matters but the visible area. Remember all the stupid "bars" in IE?

Comment: Very true. Hard to gauge the "new fold" now days with the increasingly different models of browsers, smart phones, and tablets. Seems like designing for bigger and more modern screen resolutions is a lot less common these days, and the 960gs *appears* to be a perfect middle ground when it comes to ultimately deciding which resolution to accommodate.

Comment: I'd be wary of linking to anything from w3schools - especially in light of things like http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Wow, I had no clue. Have edited my answer. Thought about deleting, but people should be aware of this information. Thanks Mike.